# Bizarre Oracle Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a large, complex query.
I added a simple date filter to the `WHERE` clause, and now I get `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Removing the rest of the query, and just selecting `id` with this single date filter still produces the error - so at least that narrows it down.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.date_column >= DATEADD(Date(), "1", -70)
```

Looking online, apparently this error is supposed to indicate a missing `FROM` clause, or a missing column list in the `SELECT` portion, etc.
But none of those things are missing from this query ...

What the heck is going on here?
I presume it has something to do with the way I used `DATEADD`, but I have no idea where to begin investigating this.
I tried `@DATEADD` instead of `DATEADD` but that made no difference.

Comment: `DATEADD()` is not an Oracle function, so you are going to get some sort of error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes it is? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Dateadd.html
Or mabye not ... idk ...

Comment: @Giffyguy: that's **not** the manual for the Oracle database. Seems to be for a tool named `DAL`(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Index_Left.html#CSHID=Function_Reference.html|StartTopic=Function_Reference.html|SkinName=Oracle)  the manual for the Oracle database is here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/toc.htm

Comment: @GordonLinoff - after some poking around I found that DAL = Document Automation Language, and is part of a product called Oracle Insurance. Beyond that I got no clue...

Comment: @Giffyguy - you have to be careful when looking up Oracle documentation, because quite often you'll get references to Oracle **products**, but which are not the Oracle **DBMS**. ACCEPT NO SUBSTITUTES!!! :-)

Comment: The other problem with online searches is they give results for random older versions. It's worth bookmarking the main documentation sections for the Oracle version you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you want something like `date_column` values in the last 70 days.  If so:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.date_column >= TRUNC(sysdate) - INTERVAL '70' DAY;
```

Your code is going to generate errors for at least two reasons -- `DATEADD()` is not Oracle and "1" is probably not a column name.  These types of problems can confuse the parser, so sometimes the error message is not 100% clear.

Comment: I'm new to Oracle, so all this `INTERVAL` syntax is confusing to me - but I just tested, and it works, so ... I'll take it! I copied the exact syntax from the sample code, taken from the official Oracle documentation for the `DATEADD()` function. Apparently Oracle has documentation for functions that don't exist? I guess I can't just google Oracle functions, and expect accurate information from Oracle.com ... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Dateadd.html

Comment: @Giffyguy - The problem is that Oracle the company has a large number of different products only one of which is Oracle the database.  It also owns a number of other relational databases and utilities.  So Oracle the company has documentation for lots of products on the oracle.com domain that are not Oracle the database.

Comment: @Giffyguy - the docs you found were for something called DAL (Document Automation Language), which is part of a product which is (or was?) called Oracle Insurance.